# PHP Syntax Error Appearing after moving Servers

Tags: php, apache, centos

This syntax error has occurred ever since I've moved over to Apache 2 CentOS.

> [Sat May 02 17:34:46 2015] [error] [client *] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/html/index.php on line

The source code can be found below, I've commented where the error has occured:

```
require('roblox.php');
$config = require('config.php');
/*if (isset($_GET['cookie'])){
    echo (new RBXLim)->get_cookie();
    return;
}*/
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;
$rbxlim = new RBXLim;
$connection = $rbxlim->get_connection();
var_dump($connection);
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['session'])){
    $_SESSION['session'] = md5(microtime().rand());
}
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    $_SESSION['premium'] = $connection->query("SELECT premium FROM registered WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION['user_id'])->fetch_assoc()['premium']; // this is where the error occurs
}
```

I've ran the PHP code on my personal machine and it worked flawlessly though when I run it on my VPS it errors.

Have any of you come across this before?

Comment: Check the version of PHP

Comment: Your original server was probably PHP 5.4+, your new one appears to be PHP <=5.3 as it seems it doesn't support array dereferencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP supports array derefencing of return values as [of PHP 5.4 only](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

Your VPS probably runs PHP 5.3 or less. You should upgrade it, as [PHP 5.3 is EOL](https://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: Yup. This appears to be the issue. I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I can. (I have version 5.3 on the VPS.)